# When I submiting form it is continously giving me error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Getting **Error:-**

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens.

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO 
tbl_customer(First_name,Last_name,Email, Mobile_number, 
Landline_number, Address_1, Address_2, City, Password, Joining_date) 
VALUES(:firstname,:lastname, :email, :mbl_nmbr, landline_nmbr, 
reg_add1, reg_add2, reg_cus_city, :pass ,jdate)");

$stmt->bindParam(":firstname",$reg_user_first_name);
$stmt->bindParam(":lastname",$reg_user_last_name);
$stmt->bindParam(":email",$reg_user_email);
$stmt->bindParam(":mbl_nmbr",$mobile_number);
$stmt->bindParam(":landline_nmbr",$landline_nmbr);
$stmt->bindParam(":reg_add1",$reg_add1);
$stmt->bindParam(":reg_add2",$reg_add2);
$stmt->bindParam(":reg_cus_city",$reg_cus_city);
$stmt->bindParam(":pass",$password);
$stmt->bindParam(":jdate",$joining_date);
```

Comment: can you specify the error? and why havent you used : for some values?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: yes because you missed : for some inputs, see landline_nmbr is without : so rather it will be :landline_nmbr and also for other fields

Comment: Thanks alot it solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above query you miss to put **":"** on bindParam.

Use this one

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO 
tbl_customer(First_name,Last_name,Email, Mobile_number, 
Landline_number, Address_1, Address_2, City, Password, Joining_date) 
VALUES(:firstname,:lastname, :email, :mbl_nmbr, :landline_nmbr, 
:reg_add1, :reg_add2, :reg_cus_city, :pass ,:jdate)");
```

I thing it will work for you.